# Listing and datakeynames

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I have got this in my ItemTemplate of the listView:

```
      <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="background-color: #FFFBD6;color: #333333;">
                <td>
               <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CommandName="Select" >'<%# Eval("MessageTitle") %>'</asp:LinkButton>
                </td>    
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

I want on the linkbuttons click to get the "MessageID"..which is my datakeyname..

So far I did this:

```
    protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string recordID = (e.Item.DataItemIndex).ToString(); //I get 0 all the time as my recordID
    Server.Transfer("~/Moderator/ObserveMessage.aspx?MessageID=" + recordID);
}
```

But it doesnt work;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.CommandArgument` Will give you the DataKeyValue for the selected Row. e.g.

You need to add `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MessageID") %>'`  to your linkbutton

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MessageID") %>'  runat="server"  CommandName="Select" >'<%# Eval("MessageTitle") %>'</asp:LinkButton>

 protected void ListView1_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string recordID = e.CommandArgument;
    Server.Transfer("~/Moderator/ObserveMessage.aspx?MessageID=" + recordID);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Muhammad..That gives me Null.. It is the Listviews event and not the linkbutton event..henceforth,,the CommandArgument of the ListView is null.. With DataList I know you could take the DataKey  from the DataKeys collection by doing something like: e.Item.SelectedIndex...But with Listview you have no such paramters

Comment: Did you set the DataKeyName to your listView control ?

Comment: I have update my answer, can you try to add CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MessageID") %>'

Comment: I stole the answer from this site..It worked: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/DataKeys-and-DataKeyNames-Property-of-Listview-or-Gridview-479.php

Comment: But that's listview dataBound event, did you try my updated answer?

Comment: I found the answer a few minutes before you posted yours..But I do understand your way of solving the problem.. If you set the CommandArgument in the linkbutton, it also works. An interesting and simpler way to solve the issue I had..Thanks for the help